# Angular and TypeScript: How should I handle this as

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, typescript

I have a question about how to handle Angular asynchronous calls.

I'm calling the following two methods in a service from a controller to get an object namely "categoryInfo"

How can I get the following methods work to return the categoryInfo and print it properly?

**Caller(in a controller) to the two methods↓**

```
console.log(this.service.getLargeCategoryList()); ←※Prints out as "undefined"
```

**Method1↓**

```
public getLargeCategoryList(): any {
            console.log('Inside getLargeCategoryList');
            this.getCategoryInfoList('', ServiceUrls.URL_FOR_TOP_CATEGORY)
                .then((data) => {
                var categoryInfo: ILCategoryInfoRes[] = data.categoryInfo;
                return categoryInfo;　←※Appears to be skipped
            }, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('Error');
                    return null;
                });
            console.log('Coming out of getLargeCategoryList');
        }
```

**Method2↓**

```
private getCategoryInfoList(parameter: any, serviceUrl: string): ng.IPromise<any> {

                var def = this.qService.defer();

                this.httpService({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: serviceUrl,
                        data: parameter
                }).success(function (data: any, status, headers, config) {
                     //Success
                    var categoryInfo: ILCategoryInfoRes[];
                    var statusInfo: IStatus[];

                    //categoryInfo = data.categoryInfo;
                    statusInfo = data.status;

                    if (statusInfo[0].statusCode == '000') {
                        def.resolve(data);
                    } else {
                        def.resolve(statusInfo);
                    }
                 }).error(function (data, status, headers, config){
                     //Error 
                    def.reject("Failed");
                 });
                return def.promise;
            }
```

Comment: The function `getLargeCategoryList` does not return anything. The `return categoryInfo;` is just returning from the promise success handler and not the from `getLargeCategoryList`

Comment: How can I make this work?

Comment: I added an answer explaining what I was talking about

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return out the promise from this function:

```
public getLargeCategoryList(): any {
  console.log('Inside getLargeCategoryList');
  return this.getCategoryInfoList('', ServiceUrls.URL_FOR_TOP_CATEGORY)
    .then((data) => {
      var categoryInfo: ILCategoryInfoRes[] = data.categoryInfo;
      return categoryInfo;　←※Appears to be skipped
    }, function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      alert('Error');
      return null;
    });
  console.log('Coming out of getLargeCategoryList');
}
```

And handle it as though it returns a promise, not a value because it **is** an asynchronous operation:

```
this.service.getLargeCategoryList()
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }):
```